# UNO is not maintaining the binding to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, observablecollection, uno

I have a MVVM ViewModel on the UNO Platform.
The ViewModel has an ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Location>? Locations { get; set; }
```

It is created in the constructor of the ViewModel:

```
this.Locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
```

The collection contents are initialized in the LoadData() method of the ViewModel as part of the Views codeBehind
OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) event handler.
The intialization is as follows:

```
List<Location> lst = await ApiClient.LocationGetAllByAccountId(MiscUtils.OrganizationId);
if (Locations != null)
{
    foreach (Location l in lst)
    {
        Locations.Add(l);
    }
}
```

When the view appears, the ComboBox is populated with the Locations, however when the app reacts to the ComboBox SelectedItem, the correct location has been selected, **BUT** I am finding that **Locations** is empty.  This prevents me from adding, updating and deleting anything in the view.  I never had this problem in WPF.  Have I wired something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. I think I had a mixture of {Binding and {x:Bind in my code that was causing the problem.